# Error on SFMC account for sFTP integration

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, sftp

We have an identified bug on our multi-org SFMC account, whereby if we add anything after `%%day%%` (e.g. `%%hour%%`, or further `%%minute%%` or `%%second%%`) in the file naming convention, we get a "File not found" error in the specified sFTP folder location.

SF is aware of this bug after we escalated the case to them, and tried to convince us to switch time zones. We did, and it did not help at all. The only way it works is if we have `%%Year%%%%Month%%%%Day%%_%%fileName%%.csv` But, since we have multiple file drops per day from our middleware, this also results in errors. We have another multi-org SFMC account in which the same, exact integration is working great with both `%%hour%%` and `%%minute%%` marks. So, it is a glitch.

While we are waiting for the bug to be fixed by Salesforce, is there an alternative way to proceed with sFTP integration?

Comment: FYI: The error "File Not Found" occurs on the second step of the automation - "Import File" activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate subfolder in the SFTP for each File Drop type and then utilize the folder with a more simple file naming pattern or choose even "No Filename Pattern" option since that subfolder should not have any other files. "No Filename Pattern" option will lock that folder and no other automation will be able to target the folder. Then, consider those points from the [official documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_triggered_automations.htm&type=5):

> An Enhanced FTP folder works with only one file drop automation, except when a filename pattern is used. When a filename pattern, which lets a single FTP folder trigger multiple automations, is used, these statements do not apply.
>
> - Don’t use the import and export folders with file drop automations.
> - Any file placed in a folder triggers the automation associated with that folder.
> - Don’t use folders created for any other purpose, such as to upload images to a portfolio, for file drop automations.
> - Folders already used by another file drop automation are locked and display as In Use.

Once you would create a subfolder in the Import or Export directories (you cannot create folders on root), then you would need to create a new [File Location](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_file_locations.htm&type=5) with "Relative location under Marketing Cloud FTP Site" option that will represent this subfolder in the Import File Activity.

Comment: Since we have 4 different files that are being dropped, does that mean we should create 4 sub-folders for each of those files?

Comment: Hello @nix9247, yes, that is what i meant 1 subfolder = 1 File Drop type

Comment: Great! If we stick with %%year%%%%month%%%%day%%_%%fileName%%.csv , how will the SFMC differentiate among multiple files dropped on the same day with basically the same name? Alternatively, I don't know if SFMC supports iterators that are not date-related.

Comment: Use should use %%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%% in your file naming pattern both in the entry step and import file step. This ensures that the import activity runs for the file that triggered the automation.

Comment: @nix9247 Yep, as SwatiMishra said you would change the expected filename in the Import File Activity as well. Check out this [article](https://gortonington.com/sfmc-file-drop-automations/) to get familiar with all options.

Comment: @nix9247 did my answer solve your problem?